# Better approach to call rest api from android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android programming. I am using rest call from android to query result and based on the queried result I allow user to navigate from one screen/activity to another. I have around 7 activity page and on each page I perform several operations for that I use rest call.

The way I am invoking is using AsyncHttpClient

Ex.

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get("http://serverurl:8080/path1/path2/path3", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

     //some code

    }
```

The one problem which I am facing is if I have to modify the url I need to modify in all the activity page.

Is there a way from where I can modify once that can be used in every activity? 
Is there a better way? Please let me know.

Comment: If im understanding, you problem is that your url is hardcoded, so you must change it on every place. Clean way: use a string resource. Java dirty way: use a static string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Retrofit

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);

  @GET("users/repos/{id}")
  Call<Repo> getRepo(@Path("id") String id);
```

}

Any kind of url changes can be done in this interface

Initialization of retrofit with base url

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Consuming Api

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
 repos.enqueue(new Callback<List<Repo>>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<List<Repo>> call, Response<List<Repo>> response) {
   //Do something with response 
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<List<String>> call, Throwable t) {
    //handle failure
  }
});
```

For more [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do API calls in your android application.

- Using a library like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), you can perform API requests without any problems by using an interface.
- You can also use the default Url connection that comes with Android to do all sorts of operations like GET and POST among others.

If you are worried about how to easily change the **endpoint (url)**, you can write your code so that you pass in a string param to your methods that way, you don't hard code the value.

I am sure there are a lot more libraries out there and normally, it is a matter of choice and taste.

I hope this helps you as you try to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a static variable.

```
public class YourClass {

    public static final String URL = "http://www.example.com/abc";

    public void performApiCall() {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        client.get(URL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            //some code
        });
    }
}
```

You can then use the URL string from other classes:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    public void performSomeOtherApiCall() {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        client.get(YourClass.URL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            //some other code
        });
    }
}
```